# Handle Scroll in particular div tag

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have absolute div tag.
On scroll start toward down I want it to scroll smoothly fully and on scroll up I want its scroll to 0

```
let isScrollStarted = false;

const websiteELement = document.querySelector("#main");
let initialScroll = websiteELement.scrollTop;
const totalHeight = websiteELement.offsetHeight + 200;

websiteELement.addEventListener("scroll", (data) => {
  const scrollY = websiteELement.scrollTop;
  

  if (scrollY > totalHeight && isScrollStarted) {
    isScrollStarted = false;
    initialScroll = scrollY;
  }
  if (scrollY === 0 && isScrollStarted) {
    isScrollStarted = false;
  }

  if (initialScroll < scrollY && !isScrollStarted) {
    console.log("Scrolling")
    isScrollStarted = true;
    websiteELement.scrollTo({
      top: totalHeight,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  } else if (initialScroll > scrollY && !isScrollStarted) {
    isScrollStarted = true;
    websiteELement.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }
  initialScroll = scrollY;
});
```

I have tested this code with window object it is running fine but for this its only working ( too slow ) If i remove isScrollStarted check in `initialScroll < scrollY` and `initialScroll > scrollY`

In this code it is printing Scrolling ( Check when scroll is about to start) but it is not scrolling till **totalHight**

How can i implement this ?

Comment: You could have tried for Intersection observer API in case of observing scrolls much better and performance wise too

Comment: OK will look at it